# iPhone - Drawing 2D with OpenGL ES, fast and simple

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I'm going to make a game for the iPhone, and I'm mostly going to be using images. I've read that using Quartz only is slow for actual games with high frame rates, so I was wondering if you guys had any good ideas for using OpenGL for rendering a game scene?

I'm going to be using a lot of images, and I want to be able to freely rotate them.

I've looked at Apple's examples GLSprite and GLPaint, but I don't really see anything I could use.

All I want to do is be able to render images at specific positions, and want to be able to rotate them.

I'm a noob at OpenGL, but I know Quartz.

Comment: You may wish to refer to the answers in this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2328487/what-should-i-learn-quartz-or-opengl-es and this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2720804/how-much-more-complex-is-it-to-draw-simple-curves-lines-and-circles-in-opengl-es , which ask something similar.  You use Core Animation, not Quartz, to animate 2-D objects in Cocoa.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at cocos-2d. It uses OpenGL instead of Quartz and supports making the kind of game you seem to want to make:

http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-iphone/